# How to safely delete huge temp files in /root/Desktop in Ububtu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, xubuntu, root

I was installing some packages in Synaptic and noticed a folder named `/root/Desktop` which had 3.7 GB in temp files, being short on space I thought of deleting the files, but feared damaging my system!
File names are:

```
tmp0D70qQm6blGGLXN6M-U-mcsCugga-mj.FDrOqsZzZtcsP0jD9o1nW0Vm4QTG7a9epCNcqOKJ-bjY WqAlaeFRonymw0OyU6Sjkb  L3gNf4zmQ6yBhxkA.zAAl8bsplFcykmH7O.JGUBLCHVZ8TxLz-8o26rm yRgUjtHJyT3e.pcT0cb1fPxkegefIn8KA7ahPH_ d_A7IEOicrM0igjd5Z0sqRVw8_BP3h5zhNhy-idBQrnTuZouUPUgW    
tmp2ih6YaOM.hPU.P5XBa_y DZDy.xRfyVQ9O6o-kMnSpE30jvHiGpynIPwZeXjFy8KQHmRj7.omL4sPHilOo_A10BBbUXp_-sijSiYR26UGQRDt0ulrM4L7CR8QGm1jCDL_ujcz8DMYriIF0fJzfl8WyNpo9ryaxZOhdDLBNRo1.TEhXwhvJVJXrBIJFIRqPk.d7MGxu-_d_DKp1T-8hd7IEGQMVt76Nen9HNSGEOo MtaLlIhR3Mc-tYdclG
tmp2qR1P3bbZ ohpE5LvpU1Qv8aSEWdTzJF16oP0saLjUCT_b9LzBDUtHK9ZISnEdzYqMFAiwVLqHtCtBiGEyoYVeyGHw_ VcDR6nz2-m94E NfNMOlYq4mYJQSJ90e80qp1jfa0nRnBMKB4KNEy8Zpsc1hKbol9oX5z3JanRSrjrYChN9VCm7r-PefSzplPTD3uPktlQ7hs_0Edn-l_80loFSsWrL9_65jVIfV141UupscuPp9LGPv 3rlko.
tmpJzX_jHF-.3M9eMeTjw24rIrFNp5VZc0jQY1G 4udfLutpQnTuip2CjZg_9xisAcb4Oyf96jVJSYhq.BBNAbPmcta2L5U cofNt95VTfSe1ezE8se38LW4lCM4jvllG8N6tqIAnFRR-SmHmux.83ZIO1InaIwCOLh3fQo1P1cZcInyRT 8-u77dg3r1iy1KUCZsT wmLDbN3cEcWDM 6vVitOdFOgFj8yObLvCFOtk9622tdwI5eVP0znnZV
```

I just moved from Xubuntu to Cinammon and from there to Gnome, so I am guessing these files are interface-related.

*Please tell me if they are safe to delete or not?*

Comment: Since they start with tmp I believe it is safe to delete them. I am not 100% sure but what can go wrong. Imagine the worst case scenario. Some application might not work. I doubt you will loose valuable data. I also doubt you will harm the OS. Try to move them first and see if everything works. Then delete them.

Comment: I have never seen files with such names, let alone in /root/Desktop, let even more alone of that size. I would not rest until I knew what application or utility writes these files. Isn't there anything you can tell from the file creation dates, or something like `head tmp...` or `strings tmp...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No one can absolutely, positively tell you this is 100% safe!

It is *very likely* to be safe (99% certainty), therefore:

1. ***[Take a full system back-up!!!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)***
2. Rename the files.

Now use the system for a while and see if you have no adverse effects.

3. Delete the files.

If anything goes wrong: *Restore the back-up!* (or rename the files back to what they were)

<sub>**You *are* taking back-ups are you???**</sub>

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Of course I do! I backup daily!!

Comment: I think a full system backup for deleting a few files beginning with "tmp" is an overkill.

Comment: @MuaadElSharif: Fantastic!  +1 for your question!

Comment: A full system backup is NEVER overkill if you have a plan. It takes me a few seconds to plug in a USB 3.0 drive and run a script to rsync and changes since my last backup. On my desktop that has lots of financial data I couldn't replace, I have scripts called by cron to back up every hour, every day, every week, and every month.

Comment: @Marc: no yearly back-ups that you store for the next 7 years?  (Section 103 of the Sarbanes-Oxley Act) **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby: I'm tempted! I could fit a century's data on a 1TB usb drive.